# ConstraintResolutionError

Tags: plutus

I'm getting the following error during the ledgerTx line of code
`"ConstraintResolutionError (TxOutRefNotFound (TxOutRef {txOutRefId = 70d473b55eaac244c821a001fe153813249c22395cb55631f34eb149937d340a, txOutRefIdx = 1}))"`

```
utxos <- utxosAt $ scriptAddress payValidator
let orefs = fst <$> Map.toList utxos
     change = _ciTxOutValue (snd (L.head (Map.toList utxos))) - (Ada.lovelaceValueOf bet)
     lookups = Constraints.typedValidatorLookups typedPayToScriptValidator
     tx = Constraints.mustSpendScriptOutput (last orefs) unitRedeemer <> Constraints.mustPayToTheScript bet change
ledgerTx <- submitTxConstraintsWith lookups tx
void $ awaitTxConfirmed $ getCardanoTxId ledgerTx
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was caused by the lookups. The combination of Constraints that resolved the issue is `let lookups = Constraints.unspentOutputs utxos <> Constraints.typedValidatorLookups typedPayToScriptValidator <> Constraints.otherScript (Scripts.validatorScript typedPayToScriptValidator)` I'm not sure exactly what these lookup constraints do and why they are necessary, but they fixed the ConstraintResolutionError

Comment: *smacks self on forehead* - I've been stuck on the exact same error. I couldn't figure out why it couldn't find a TxOutRef that I had just found a few lines earlier using utxosTxOutTxAt, but it's the lookups! 
thanks!